# Meaning of ${VERSION:2:1} =~ [U-Z]

Tags: bash, shell

What's the meaning of the following expression?

```
${VERSION:2:1} =~ [U-Z]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It checks if the 3rd character of the variable `$VERSION` is a character in between `U` and `Z`.

- `${var:M:N}` prints `N` characters starting from the `M` position:

  ```
  $ v="12345"
  $ echo ${v:2:1}
  3
  ```
- `=~` is a regex comparison.
- `[U-Z]` is a range from `U` to `Z`.

#### Test

```
$ v="abWcd"
$ [[ ${v:2:1} =~ [U-Z] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

$ v="abAcd"
$ [[ ${v:2:1} =~ [U-Z] ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: Thanks! But do not delete your answer, it's got a good explanation!

Comment: No, that will be duplicate now, please add those 3 lines in your answer if you like.

Comment: That's very kind of you, @anubhava. I got some of it.